# Excel - create new sheet for label based on cells

Tags: excel, cells

I have a 'master' Excel sheet and I'm trying to extrapolate some of the data into new sheets to print on labels.

Basically I have 5 cells which always remain the same (A1, B1, C1, D1, E1)

Then I have a series of rows which need to be filled in each day by the user

(A4, B4, C4, D4)

(A5, B5, C5, D5)

(A6, B6, C6, D6)

(A7, B7, C7, D7)

(A8, B8, C8, D8)

(A9, B9, C9, D9)

(A10, B10, C10, D10) etc

At the end of the day, I need to generate a label (or sheet) to print, one for each of the rows. The label needs to include the 5 fields and each row entered ie:

(A1) (B1) (C1) (D1) (E1)

(A4) (B4) (C4) (D4)

to

(A1) (B1) (C1) (D1) (E1)

(A10) (B10) (C10) (D10)

Ideally, if this could be automated into a single button press to generate all the new 'sheets' and then I can print each one off from there.

My Excel knowledge doesn't really extend much beyond 'AutoSum' for columns and rows etc so I'm completely out of my depth here.

If you can point me in the right direction, I'd be very happy and it will save me hours in collating all this data

Thanks very much

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I came up with a round-about solution if anyone is interested...

I created a new sheet and set the page size up to the label size.

For each page (label) I recreated the 'text labels' and gave the agecent cell the formula =Sheet1!A1 (for A1... same for B1, C1, D1 & E1)

Then for each of the data rows I did the same with formula =Sheet1!A4 (& same for B4, C4, D4)

All of these cells fit nicely into the "print page boundries"

I then recreated these cells into 24 other "print page boundries" and changed the code on the data rows to =Sheet1!A5 =Sheet1!A6 ... =Sheet1!A25 etc

All I have to do now is hit print and print the number of pages that I have data rows for...

Probably not pretty, but it does the trick!